# Energy Imparted by a Magnetic Field

Tags: electromagnetism, energy, energy-conservation

As I understand it, when you switch on an electromagnet it generates a magnetic field that pervades all space, imparting potential/kinetic energy to every object with which it interacts. Where does this energy come from? And how is it transmitted?

Please use layman's terms and simple maths as far as possible, it's been quite a while since I studied physics.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnet#Magnetic_field_created_by_a_current

Comment: The energy comes from whatever generates the electric current, which in turn generates the magnetic field, such as a battery. I am not sure what specifically you are asking with "How it is transmitted", do you mean the magnetic field though space?

Comment: Thanks for your help.

By "how is it transmitted" I mean what is the step by step process by which energy is transferred from the source (battery or generator), to the motion of an object interacting with the magnetic field? Including the mechanism by which force is transmitted through space in magnetic field interactions.

Answer (score 1):

There is energy in the magnetic field,  $\mathcal U_B=B^2/(2\mu_0)$ in MKS units (as long as no magnetic materials are around).

The act of turning on the magnetic field creates a changing $B$ field for a short time.  A changing $B$ field creates an electric field, and this can cause current to flow in conductors.  So there is some energy there too.

Exactly how much energy thus depends on the environment. Does that help at all?

Answer (score 1):

Frankly, no one really knows! In the day of Ampere, Faraday, and Maxwell they thought that the so-called ether passed the energy from one "ether particle" to its neighbor-much like a fire brigade passing a bucket of water along a line from hand to hand. Nowadays, there is no real certitude about precisely how the energy propagates through space. We can describe the process in terms of wave equations for the electric and magnetic fields. But this is a formal, mathematical description-and the transmission of energy through empty space really has the character of a postulate.

Answer (score 0):

The magnetic field is created by the current. Therefore, the energy of the magnetic field is supplied by the current.

A magnetic field does no work on charged particles. This is because, it exerts a force $\vec{F} = q(\vec{v}\times\vec{B})$ on it, $q$ being the charge, $\vec{v}$ being the velocity of the charge and $\vec{B}$ being the magnetic field. Clearly, $\vec{F}\cdot d\vec{x} = 0$.

When a magnetic field lifts something, it does work on the magnetic dipoles. In simple terms, dipoles are like tiny magnets with north and south poles. A "magnetic material" has plenty of them. The large electromagnet attracts all of them toward itself. While doing so, it has to do work.

(A slightly more technical explanation would be - If $\vec{\mu}$ is the dipole moment, then the force on it is $\vec{F} = \nabla(\vec{\mu}\cdot\vec{B})$. Work done by this force is usually not zero. That is, $dW  = \vec{F}\cdot d\vec{x} \ne 0$.)